# Is ControlSend known to work with windows 11 File Explorer?

Tags: autohotkey

- `ControlSend,, ^{a}, ahk_class CabinetWClass` , nothing is selected in the inactive File Explorer window
- `ControlSend, ahk_parent, {enter}, C:\temp ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe Explorer.EXEs`, the selected folder does not get opened
- `ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^a, ahk_class CabinetWClass`, does not work
- `ControlSend, DirectUIHWND2 , ^{a}, ahk_class CabinetWClass`, does not work

I really need this feature, is explorer no longer a win32 software? Has anyone ever managed to get this to work?